# What works to pass touches through to (and display all) subviews?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, uitoolbar

I have the following subview chain:

```
UIViewController.view -+
                       |-> UIView (subclass) -+
                       |                      +-> UIToolbar 
                       |
                       +------------------------> UIWebView
```

In the subclass, I override its `-touchesEnded:forEvent:` method in order to hide and show the `UIToolbar` on a single tap touch, through a `CAAnimation`, as well as issue an `NSNotification` that causes the view controller to hide its navigation bar.

If I do not add the `UIWebView` as a subview to the view controller's view, then this works properly.

If I then add the `UIWebView` as a subview of the view controller's view, then the `UIToolbar` does not appear, and I do not get the animation effect. The `UIWebView` responds to touches but the subclassed `UIView` does not. The notification does get fired, though, and the navigation bar does get hidden.

What is the best way to arrange these subviews so that:

1. The `UIToolbar` can be made to slide on and off the screen
2. The `UIWebView` is visible can still receive its typical touch-events: zoom in/out and double-tap to reset zoom level

A correct answer will meet both criteria.

---

**EDIT**

I made some progress with this, but I cannot distinguish touch events and thus I fire a toolbar hide/show method when it should not be fired.

I set the view controller's view property to the `UIView` subclass, and I inserted the web view at the top of the `-subviews` array via `[self.view insertSubview:self.webView atIndex:0]`.

I added the following method to the `UIView` subclass:

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint) point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *subview = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        [self toggleToolbarView:self];

    // get touches
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];

    NSLog(@"subview: %@", subview);
    NSLog(@"touches: %@", touches);

    // individual touches
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        switch (touch.phase) {
            case UITouchPhaseBegan:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseBegan");
                break;
            case UITouchPhaseMoved:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseMoved");
                break;
            case UITouchPhaseCancelled:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseCancelled");
                break;
            case UITouchPhaseStationary:
                NSLog(@"UITouchPhaseStationary");
                break;      
            default:
                NSLog(@"other phase...");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return subview;
}
```

The method `-toggleToolbarView:` triggers an `NSTimer`-timed `CAAnimation` that hides/shows a `UIToolbar*`.

The problem is that a touch-drag combination causes `-toggleToolbarView:` to be fired (as well as zooming in or out of the web view). What I would like to do is cause `-toggleToolbarView:` to be fired only when there is a touch-only event.

When I call the above method `-hitTest:withEvent:`, it looks like the `UIWebView` sucks up the touches. The two `NSLog` statements show that the `UIView*` that is returned from the parent `UIView*`'s `-hitTest:withEvent:` is either the `UIWebView` or the `UIToolbar` (when it is on-screen and touched). The `touches` array is empty and therefore the touch event types cannot be distinguished.

There's one more thing I will try, but I wanted to record this attempt here in case others have quick suggestions. Thanks for your continued help.

---

**EDIT II**

I made some progress with getting the `UIWebView` to pinch/zoom and respond to double-taps. I can also hide/show the toolbar with single-taps.

Instead of messing with the `UIWebView` instance's private `UIScroller`, I access its inner, private `UIWebDocumentView`. But the web view as a whole does not redraw properly after zooming in.

What this means: If my document contains a PDF or an SVG vector illustration, for example, zooming in causes the contents to be blurry, as if the image tiles that make up the rendered PDF or vector illustration contents are not being re-rendered at the new zoom factor.

For the purposes of documenting this, I will:

1. Call the `UIView (subclass)` instead `ViewerOverlayView`
2. The `UIWebView` is called `ViewerWebView`

Both are subclasses of `UIView` and `UIWebView`, respectively.

My `ViewerWebView` contains a new ivar (with `@property` + `@synthesized`):

```
UIView *privateWebDocumentView;
```

(This `UIView` is actually a pointer to a `UIWebDocumentView` instance, but to avoid Apple flagging the app for refusal I cast this to a `UIView` for the simple purpose of passing it touch events.)

The implementation of `ViewerWebView` overrides `-hitTest:withEvent:`

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *_subview = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    self.privateWebDocumentView = _subview;
    return _subview;
}
```

My `ViewerOverlayView` contains new ivars (with `@property` + `@synthesized`):

```
ViewerWebView *webView;
UIView *webDocumentView;
```

In the implementation of the overlay view, I override `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `-touchesMoved:withEvent:` and `-touchesEnded:withEvent:`

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.touchHasMoved = NO;
    if (self.webView) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        self.webDocumentView = [self.webView hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.webDocumentView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.touchHasMoved = YES;
    if (self.webView) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        self.webDocumentView = [self.webView hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.webDocumentView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(!self.touchHasMoved) 
        [self toggleToolbarView:self];
    if (self.webView) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
        self.webDocumentView = [self.webView hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:event];
    }
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.webDocumentView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

In the view controller, I do the following:

1. Instantiate the `ViewerOverlayView` and add it as a subview of the view controller's `view` property
2. Instantiate the view controller's `ViewerWebView` instance and insert it at the bottom of the subviews array
3. Set the `ViewerOverlayView` web view property to the view controller's web view

So now my transparent `ViewerOverlayView` correctly passes zoom/stretch/double-tap touch events to the `ViewerWebView` instance's private `UIWebDocumentView` instance. The `UIWebDocumentView` then resizes.

However, the content does not redraw itself with the new scale. So vector-based content (e.g. PDF, SVG) looks blurry when zooming in.

Here's what the view looks like without scaling, nice and sharp:

[image: UIWebView, no scaling]

Here's what the view looks like when zoomed in, which is not as sharp as it would otherwise be without all this custom event munging:

[image: UIWebView, blurry zoom]

Interestingly, I can only rescale between two zoom levels. Once I stop double-tap-stretching to zoom in at any level, it then "snaps back" to the frame you see in the image above.

I tried `-setNeedsDisplay` on the `ViewerWebView` and its inner `UIWebDocumentView` instance. Neither method call worked.

Despite wanting to avoid private methods, because I want to eventually get this app approved, I also tried [this suggestion](http://pinchzoom.com/blog/items/view/1386/one-of-the-problems-with-the-uikit-at-the-moment-is-an-issue-embedding-a-uiwebview-within-a-table) of accessing the private `UIWebDocumentView` method `-_webCoreNeedsDisplay`:

```
[(UIWebDocumentView *)self.webDocumentView _webCoreNeedsDisplay];
```

This method caused the app to crash from an `unrecognized selector` exception. Perhaps Apple has changed the name of this method from SDK 3.0 to 3.1.2.

Unless there is a way to cause the web view to redraw its contents, I guess I'm going to have to scrap the transparent overlay view and just draw a web view, in order to get the web view to work properly. That sucks!

If anyone has thoughts about redrawing-after-scaling, please feel free to add an answer.

Thanks again to all of you for your input. As an aside, I did not cancel the bounty on this question -- I do not know why it was not automatically awarded to the first answer to this thread, as I was otherwise expecting to happen from previous experience.

---

**EDIT III**

I found this web page that shows [how to subclass the application window](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/) so as to observe taps and forward those taps to the view controller.

It's not necessary to implement its delegate everywhere throughout the application, only where I want to observe taps on `UIWebView`, so this may work really well for a document viewer.

So far, I can observe taps, hide and show the toolbar, and the `UIWebView` behaves like a web view. I can zoom in and out of the web view and the document is re-rendered properly.

While it would be nice to learn how to manage taps in a more generic fashion, this looks like a pretty great solution.

Comment: How big are your views, and how are they overlapping? Is your custom UIView just the size of the UIToolbar, or are you wanting a tap anywhere on the screen to hide it?

Comment: The views are the size of the screen. They are fully overlapping. The custom UIView is the size of the screen so as to accept touches anywhere on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried cancelling the toggle when a simple touch progresses into the drag/zoom phase? I guess cancelling a timer that delays the start of the animation just long enough to detect the change from touch to drag/zoom?

Comment: I do not know of a way to programmatically distinguish between touch and touch-drag events, as the `[event allTouches]` array is empty. Because of the empty array, I have no way of issuing a notification to cancel the timer, for example.

Comment: Interesting that you cancelled the bounty, even when you had an answer to your original question. I'm new around here, but it doesn't seem right that the bounty disappears, even if you did change your question.

Comment: It looks like I lost reputation points from setting up the bounty, so I'm not sure what happened here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I'm reading your question, you want to **intercept the events** to trigger some action (animate toolbar, post notification), while allowing the event to also reach its natural destination.

If I were trying to do this, I would put the `UIToolbar` directly as a subview of the `UIViewController.view`. The `UIWebView` remains a direct subview also.

The `UIViewController.view` should be a subclass of `UIView`, and it needs to override

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

The view can side-step being part of the event processing by sending back the view that you want to receive the event (UIToolbar or UIWebView), while you still get a chance to trigger the actions you want.

An example might be:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint) point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* subview = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    /* Use the event.type, subview to decide what actions to perform */
    // Optionally nominate a default event recipient if your view is not completely covered by subviews
    if (subview == self) return self.webViewOutlet;
    return subview;
}
```

Comment: Keeping the views in separate subclasses is a requirement for a correct answer.

Comment: In that case, can you put the `UIWebView` inside the `UIView (subclass)` in your diagram above? That would also allow you to override `-hitTest:` and use the same approach.

Comment: Is there a way to segregate `event.type` to know what kind of touch is taking place? For example, a touch-and-drag should only move the web view, but this is also treated like a touch and this triggers the subview containing the toolbar. Is there a way to distinguish between "touch-and-drag" and plain "touch"? There is `if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches)` but I don't see any other event type or subtype that breaks this down further.

Comment: I'm not proficient with the touch event deciphering, but this SO answer looks appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990870/handling-touches-inside-uiwebview/1755375#1755375

Answer (score 1):

If you start by adding the UIView subclass to the view controller's view, then add the UIWebView as you describe, the UIWebView is going to completely cover the UIView subclass (assuming both views are completely overlapping as you mention in the question comments).

It sounds like you don't want that - you want the subclass *above* the web view. You need to either add them to the view controller's view in the opposite order (add web view, then add custom UIView) or call:

```
[viewContoller.view insertSubview:webView belowSubview:subclass];
```

With that out of the way, let's talk about how to intercept the touch events. I'm going to suggest a different approach that allowed me to do something kind of similar. [Here's the question and answer I created for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273450/iphone-detecting-user-inactivity-idle-time-since-last-screen-touch) - feel free to look there for more details on this technique.

The idea is that you subclass UIApplication and override the -sendEvent: method. Yours will look something like this, I suppose:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    if ([allTouches count] > 0) {
        UITouch *touch = [allTouches anyObject];
        if ([allTouches count] == 1 && touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded && touch.tapCount == 1) {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

I don't expect this will get you 100% there, but hopefully it's a start. In particular, you may want to play around with the if condition that checks the properties of the UITouches you're dealing with. I'm not sure if I'm including the right checks or if they'll catch the exact condition you're looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: I am inserting the web view into the view controller `-subviews` array at index 0 to get it to become visible and responsive to touches. However, this causes the subview containing the toolbar to become unresponsive.

Comment: You need to use addSubview: or one of the insertSubview: methods. Don't add the view to the subviews array directly.

Comment: I have used both methods. I don't think I want to subclass the application delegate, since this component that requires subclassing is only a small (if important) part of the application as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, what about this:

-In your custom `UIView` subclass, add a pointer to your `UIWebView`

-Add an ivar to the `UIView` subclass, `BOOL hasMoved;`

-In the `UIView` subclass, override the touch methods like this:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    hasMoved = NO;
    [webView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    hasMoved = YES;
    [webView touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(!hasMoved) [self hideToolbar];
    [webView touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

And then put the custom view on top of the web view. Seems too simple, and it probably is -- some magic may be required to handle multiple touches correctly, and you may need to use a `NSTimer` in the `touchesBegan:` method to as delay to handle double tap situations, but I think the general idea is sound...perhaps?

Comment: In doing this, the application hangs with an infinite loop at `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` once the first touch occurs, which prompts a force-quit. I'm surprised this is so difficult!

Comment: That's very strange. I can't imagine why. I set up a demo project to verify this and I didn't encounter an infinite loop -- however, it didn't work as expected. I've found another half solution which I'll post for historic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Take 2: same as above, but override the methods as follows:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    hasMoved = NO;
    [[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    hasMoved = YES;
    [[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(!hasMoved) [self toggleToolbar];
    [[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This works...sort of. This allows you to drag the web view around. But it isn't handling other touch events properly (following links, pinching, anything). So. Probably not very useful, but it was progress to me!

Comment: I rearranged views and noticed that this subview will accept drags. No zooming, though.