# Get hit test event type

Tags: objective-c, hittest, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

Is there a way to know if the `hitTest:withEvent:` method is being thrown because of a touchesBegan, touchesMoved or touchesEnded event?

by now I only do:

```
if([event type]==UIEventTypeTouches)
{

}
```

but this is not exclusive enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found it here: [What works to pass touches through to (and display all) subviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856411/what-works-to-pass-touches-through-to-and-display-all-subviews)