# How to pass single touch events to super view in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebView` to display pdf. I wanna handle touch events on webview.
There are two conditions, my WebView should handle double touch events and gestures, and i wanna pass single tap/touch events to super view.

Can any one please tell me how to differentiate the touch events in `UIWebView` and how to pass specific touch events to its super view?

to get the touch events i am subclassing the uiwebview and im overriding the hitTest method in subclass.

Comment: it seems to be a duplicate of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990870/handling-touches-inside-uiwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that post is not answering your question, you should check out [this article](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/).

I took a similar but slightly different approach: I subclassed a UIView, which contains a UIWebView (and other controls), and override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass web view and Use hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) method in subclass as follows:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let hitTestingView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) {
        if shouldHandleTouch // Logic on which this view should handle touch or not. If you don't want to handle always then return nil {
            return hitTestingView
        } else {
            return nil
        }  
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```