# UIWebView touch event not getting fired

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, detection, uitouch

I am new to iPhone Developer,

I want to detect touch in my webview so i tried this but this method is not getting fired,

in `.h` file

```
@interface EpubReaderViewController : UIViewController
```

in `.m` file

```
... 
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"Touch detected") ;   
}
...
```

Even i tried this also,

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches began");
}
```

**Thanks In Advance !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User is going to zoom in and zoom out on the website, as well as touch to click hpyerlinks etc. That'w shy touch methods won't respond for `UIWebView`.

If you want to enable touch, you might need to subclass `UIWebview` while it is forbidded in developer docs, check following threads for more discussion-

[Handling touches inside UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990870/handling-touches-inside-uiwebview)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122745/how-to-detect-touch-event-in-uiwebview

[How to intercept touches events on a MKMapView or UIWebView objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049889/how-to-intercept-touches-events-on-a-mkmapview-or-uiwebview-objects)

[Handling touches inside UIWebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990870/handling-touches-inside-uiwebview)

You can go through this tutorial as well -

http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way

Comment: Subclassing is not a good option as i had mentioned earlier as well.It is mentioned in the developer docs as well. You can try this which is in one of threads above - http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

Comment: the link which you have provide that uses `(void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and this method is deprecated after iOS 5.0 and i am using iOS 5.1

Comment: We are not here to do code for you? you need to do that yourself, we can just help you if you are stuck anywhere?

Comment: dude i am telling because i am very new here and i really don't know how to do this, and tutorial you have provided is deprecated so i told you to do this small thing. if you can then it will be really appreciated.