# swipe up/down gesture not working inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIWebView hosted inside UIViewController,
I manage to add the right\left gestures in the following way:

```
var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
self.webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

The problem that it's not working with up/down directions:

```
var swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swiped:")
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
self.webView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

I think it's because of the scrolling and I also tried to add it to the scrollview but it still doesn't recognize the up/down gestures:

```
self.webView.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

**UPDATE**:
I tried Harry answer but it override the default action of swipe up/down and I can't scroll the page:

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

self.webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeUp)
self.webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeDown)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18834365/1282896

Comment: @Harry this answer is in ObjectiveC, how can I do it in swift?

Answer (score 3):

Add gesture recogniser to `self.view` not `UIWebView` instance.

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
```

Add these two lines after adding up/down gesture recognisers to web view.

```
self.webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeUp)
self.webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeDown)
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's working but it override the default action of swipe up/down and I can't scroll the page

Comment: Sorry but I still can't scroll, I'm getting the gesture I defined but can't scroll up/down the UIWEBVIEW, what am I doing wrong? I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

In case of someone is still working on it, this solved my problem :

```
webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

upGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
upGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
upGesture.delegate = self;
[webView.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:upGesture];

downGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
downGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
downGesture.delegate = self;
[webView.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:downGesture];



- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UISwipeGestureRecognizer class]] && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]];
}
```